# Compare two folders of files in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to read all the files in one folder, and then look for that file in a second folder so they can be compared in Excel (looking for changes in key locations). So for instance if we had these files:

```
folder one
   test1
   test2
   test3

folder two
   test1
   test2
   test4
```

...then the code would return test1 and test2, as the other two are unique.

Normally I use Dir for working with lists of files, but that only works on one folder at a time. I suspect there's an easy solution for this, but I've always used Dir and none of MS's examples I can find avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dir to pull a list of the contents of each folder.  Concatenate those two lists into one big list, called 'BigList'

Sort the list using something like this: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/3/24/applying-an-alphabetical-sort-to-your-vba-array-list

Then, iterate through the sorted list.  With each iteration of the for loop, save the current value for comparison to the next value.  If the values are the same, then save the value to a new list, say 'duplicate values'.  Then keep going until you are through 'big list' and you should have the list you want in 'duplicate values'